Would a lender deposit money in my account and want me to send back
I applied for a loan and was told I was approved they said they were going to deposit a small amount and I was to send it back and they would release to loan amount is this legit? And the amount that was mentioned was 850 I believe

Nope.  It's a scam.  Found the closest similar scam thread I could to close this against.
